# Rails to send via postfix mail with dynamic domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

an application has multiple tenants and emails should reflect the domain of that tenant.  In fact, the mailer defines:

```
    from_string = 'do-not-reply@' + shop.shop_value.email_host
    subject_string = 'your order at ' + shop.name
    mail(
      from: from_string,
      to:  consumer.email,
      subject: subject_string 
    )
```

for then processing via postfix.  However, this appears to be processed via the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` configuration of *probably* myhostname

```
myhostname = maindomain.tld
mydestination = $myhostname, maindomain.tld, localhost.online, , localhost
```

leading to the following logged error

```
 Delivered mail 6442d7c523bf1_7fab24fe0933c6@maindomain.tld.mail
[...]
] OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=[::1]:25 state=error: certificate verify failed (hostname mismatch)):
```

Now I have seen suggestions of setting in the relevant environment file

```
openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```

but that seems to always refer to a `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {}` block...  and there is no purpose in defining `address, port, domain, disable_start_tls` as the environment is set with:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

postfix runs as an SMTP server, but this server is configured as send-only.  The domains however are set up with SPF and DKIM for proper handlling by other servers.

Three questions arise:
1 - `myhostname` could be [configured as an array](https://serverfault.com/questions/624373/using-multiple-myhostname-in-postfix). But how would rails know how to hand off to postfix? and is it necessary?
2 - would the following command be acceptable to rails (and quicker to implement):

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
}
```

i.e. smtp_settings are still percolating to sendmail processing.
3 - is there a way to accomplish the goal via `sendmail_settings` ?  The [rails guide is rather thin](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) on examples for `:arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
}
```

is acceptable to rails and allows email to pass to postfix.